# What are the dangerous operations that need to be prohibited on a hosted git repository?

Tags: git, gitolite

I am looking into the tools neccessary to give other people write access to a git repository. I understand that git repositories are accessed using SSH with a locked-in command like *gitosis* or *gitolite*. I learned that git, unlike Subversion, which simply doesn't support any history-changing operations, has certain operations that can actually destroy data, for example `git push --force`. Are there more such operation that need to be denied to remote users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git push --force` is really the only one that you need to worry about.  The other one that could cause issues would be removing a branch, but at least with gitolite if you can't push --force then you can't delete a branch.